# Powershell - Add header during input-csv command

Tags: powershell, csv, header

I'm looking for adding header to a csv file without header, and without information about columns number.

I have this code for csv file which I know column count :

```
    $Content = Import-Csv "C:\temp\input.csv" -Delimiter ';' -Header "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23"
```

Which is the best way to create an header like mine, automatically ?
Is "Header" parameter can be an arraylist of string value ?

I should code something like this :

```
$array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
for ($i=1; $i -lt $Columns; $i++)
{
        $array.add($i.ToString())
}
```

Comment: In fact, I wanted to create an header without hardcoding column value, in order to use it for any csv input file.

see below my auto answer ;)

Comment: that's better, and easier than my way, thanks ;)

Comment: Great; for tidyness I've added it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

To make my comment into an answer:

The array construction operator `..` makes an array of numbers, e.g. `1..5` is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and if you pass an array of numbers to `-Header` it will be turned into strings automatically, because of the way PowerShell types work - header is expecting a string array.

So you can create an array of however many numbers there are, like so:

```
-Header (1..$Columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found my error :

```
$CSVFile = Get-Content $csvTemp
$Columns = ($CSVFile[0].split(";")).Count
[string[]]$tab = @()    
for ($i=1; $i -lt $Columns; $i++){
   $tab+= $i.ToString()
} 
$content = import-csv "c:\temp\test.csv" -delimiter ';' -header $tab
```